# Doctrine relation between two entities

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am trying to rewrite my website to symfony2/doctrine.
The tables use MyISAM so no foreign keys.

I simply can't convert the below query to two entities and make a relation that works. Is it because I use MyISAM?

```
SELECT p.productid, p.price, d.description FROM product p INNER JOIN description d ON p.productid = d.productid;
```

In the `product` entity I have tried this but still no go:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Description")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="productid", referencedColumnName="productid")
 */
protected $description;
```

Comment: And what's in your `description` entity? What error are you having?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with MyISAM. Doctrine works even without foreign keys (though the schema tool usually enforces them). Check the generated DQL with `$query->getSQL()` and verify your expected results against the result of your query